# Lightning Web Component - Must provide at least one of the parameters - 'fields', 'layoutTypes', 'optionalFields'. Update Record

Tags: lightning-web-components, wire

I'm trying to run a simple update action on a record that I queried initially using a wired method. After prepare the recordInput object I get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "ok": false,
    "status": 400,
    "statusText": "Bad Request",
    "body": {
      "message": "Must provide at least one of the parameters - 'fields', 'layoutTypes', 'optionalFields'.",
      "statusCode": 400,
      "errorCode": "INVALID_INPUT_COMBINATION"
    }
  }
}
```

This is how my call looks like:

```js
updateCustomSetting(){
        var customSettingRecordId = '';

        //loop over records coming from controller
        this.customsettingFromQuery.forEach(function(element) {
            if(element.Name === 'TEST-EMORAN'){
                console.log('ASSIGNING VALUE');                
                customSettingRecordId = element.Id;
                console.log('ASSIGNED:'+customSettingRecordId);
            }                
        });

        // === FIELDS ====
        const fields = {};
        fields[CUSTOM_SETTING_ID.fieldApiName] = customSettingRecordId;
        fields[SEND_LOCATION_EVERY.fieldApiName] = this.sendEvery;
        fields[NAME.fieldApiName] = 'TEST-EMORAN';

        const recordInput = { fields };
        recordInput.fields = fields;

        console.log('recordInput'+JSON.stringify(recordInput));

        updateRecord(recordInput)
            .then(() => {
                console.log('done!');
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Record Is Updated',
                        variant: 'sucess',
                    }),
                );
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('error' + JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
            });

    }
```

the content of the input record looks like this:

```
recordInput{"fields":{"Id":"a055B000003NqfyQAC","cloudmobile__Send_Every__c":"5","Name":"TEST-EMORAN"}}
```

Is anything I'm missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below details are applicable based on this assumption (and based on results of a quick test that I performed) that you are trying to update a custom setting record.

I started by verifying that Custom Settings are supported by [UI-API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_object_info_directory.htm) which forms the base of the [`updateRecord()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_update_record) function, and it does. Then I tried updating a custom setting record from POSTMAN and it worked fine. Then I tried to update the same record from a LWC utilizing this function, and ended up with the same error that you are receiving.

It seems **this is a bug** while making an update on a Custom Setting record from a LWC. Even if the [`updateRecord()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_update_record) **call returned an error** response, the **custom setting record actually got updated**.

This definitely needs to be opened as a case to Salesforce Support.

Comment: I think it has to do more with security, custom settings are config records and not normal records. An lwc component cant be hosted in public site /community and a guest user can update(via JS hacks) them which might not always  be safe and secure.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal could be true and ideally it should be a consistent behavior either allow or don’t. But I could see as noted in the details that the response suggests the update failed but the record was on the other hand updated successfully.

Comment: Thanks @JayantDas I will create a support ticket, as you mentioned the Custom Setting gets updated correctly even the error shows in the console, good catch

Comment: @Edgar Please do let this thread know what you hear back from the support team. Once you get the details, it will be good to know if this is a bug or should not have been allowed at first place.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to get rid of this line:

```
recordInput.fields = fields;
```

That line is not there if you check out the documentation:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_update_record

I was able to get updateRecord to work using the documentation as an example.